# main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: Car.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, c++

I am using zybook, and it requires for me to create a program that maintains the inventory of a car rental agency.

The three files for this program are:

`car.h` - Class declaration
`car.cpp` - Class definition
`main.cpp` - `main()` function and other functions as described

When I wrote the program, I am getting an error:

```
main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: Car.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include "Car.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
car.cpp:3:10: fatal error: Car.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "Car.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Car.h"
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void addCar(vector<Car>& cars);
//bool deleteCar(vector<Car>& cars);
bool updateCarCondition(vector<Car>& cars);
void displayCar(vector<Car>& cars);
void displayAllCars(vector<Car>& cars);
bool rentCar(vector<Car>& cars);
bool returnCar(vector<Car>& cars);

int main(){
    char option;
    vector<Car> cars;

    while (true){
        cout << "CAR RENTAL AGENCY MENU" << endl;
        cout << "a - Add car to inventory" << endl;
        cout << "d - Delete car by id from inventory" << endl;
        cout << "u - Update car by id condition in inventory" << endl;
        cout << "s - Display one car by id from inventory" << endl;
        cout << "i - Display list of all cars in inventory" << endl;
        cout << "c - Rent a car by id in inventory" << endl;
        cout << "r - Return a car by id in inventory" << endl;
        cout << "q - Quit" << endl;

        cout << "Choose an option: " << endl;
        cin >> option;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;

        switch(option){
            case 'a': addCar(cars);
                      break;

            //case 'd': deleteCar(cars);
                      //break;

            case 'u': updateCarCondition(cars);
                      break;

            case 's': displayCar(cars);
                      break;

            case 'i': displayAllCars(cars);
                      break;

            case 'c': rentCar(cars);
                      break;

            case 'r': returnCar(cars);
                      break;

            case 'q': break;

            default: cout << "Please enter a valid option" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void addCar(vector<Car>& cars){
    int id, year;
    string model, make, condition;

    cout << "ADD CAR TO INVENTORY" << endl;

    cout << "Enter an ID: " << endl;
    cin >> id;
    cout << "Enter the make: " << endl;
    cin >> make;
    cout << "Enter the model: " << endl;
    cin >> model;
    cout << "Enter the year: " << endl;
    cin >> year;
    cout << "Enter the condition (new, slighty_used, used): " << endl;
    cin >> condition;

    Car car(id, make, model, year, condition);

    cars.push_back(car);
}

/*bool deleteCar(vector<Car>& cars){
    cout << "REMOVE CAR FROM INVENTORY" << endl;

    int id;

    cout << "Enter the ID of the car to delete: " << endl;
    cin >> id;

    vector<Car>::iterator it;

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
        if (cars.at(i).Getid() == id){
            //Car const& const_car = cars.at(i);
            //std::vector<Car>::iterator itr = std::find(cars.begin(), cars.end(), const_car);
            it = cars.at(i);
            cars.erase(it);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}*/

bool updateCarCondition(vector<Car>& cars){
    cout << "UPDARE CAR CONDITION IN INVENTORY" << endl;

    int id;
    string condition;

    cout << "Enter the ID of the car to update condition: " << endl;
    cin >> id;

    cout << "Enter the condition (new, slighty_used, used): " << endl;
    cin >> condition;

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
        if (cars.at(i).Getid() == id){
            cars.at(i).Setcondition(condition);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void displayCar(vector<Car>& cars){
    cout << "DISPLAY CAR IN INVENTORY" << endl;

    int id;

    cout << "Enter the ID of the car to display: " << endl;
    cin >> id;

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
        if (cars.at(i).Getid() == id){
            cars.at(i).displayCar();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void displayAllCars(vector<Car>& cars){
    cout << "DISPLAY ALL CARS IN INVENTORY" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
        cars.at(i).displayCar();
    }
}

bool rentCar(vector<Car>& cars){
    cout << "RENT CAR IN INVENTORY" << endl;

    int id;

    cout << "Enter the ID of the car to rent: " << endl;
    cin >> id;

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
        if (cars.at(i).Getid() == id){
            if (cars.at(i).Getrented()){
                cout << "Car is already rented" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            else if (cars.at(i).Getrented() == false){
                cout << "Car has been successfully rented to you" << endl;
                cars.at(i).toggleRented();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Car " << id << " not found in inventory" << endl;
    return false;
}

bool returnCar(vector<Car>& cars){
    cout << "RENT CAR TO INVENTORY" << endl;

    int id;

    cout << "Enter the ID of the car to return: " << endl;
    cin >> id;

    for (int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
        if (cars.at(i).Getid() == id){
            if (cars.at(i).Getrented()){
                cars.at(i).toggleRented();
                cout << "Car returned successfully!!" << endl;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Car " << id << " not found in inventory" << endl;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is your `car.h` named `car.h` will a lowercase c or an uppercase C?

Comment: Unix filesystems are generally case-sensitive. There are those that aren't, but the one you're likely using is case-sensitive: `car.h` and `Car.h` are two different files. This is a simple typo in your code.

Comment: @Wieland, , i tried lowercase c and uppercase C, but unfortunately I am still getting same error. I don't what is wrong with it, it is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Kusalananda,  i tried lowercase c and uppercase C, but unfortunately I am still getting same error. I don't what is wrong with it, it is driving me crazy.

Comment: If it still says that it can't find `Car.h`, then you have not changed the correct file. You should probably show us a directory listing with the files in the source code directory too. If you have used any options on the command line (or Makefile) that modifies the include search paths, then it would be helpful to see the full compilation command too.

Comment: If the #include line matches the exact filename of the header file (including case) then are you sure all three files are in the same directory.  Using double quotes on the #include line tells the compiler to look in the same directory as the file it is compiling.